# What ports do I need to open on Docker container when running Pulse in Tomcat in the container?

Tags: docker, geode, pulse

I'm running Geode (v1.14.0) servers/locators in Docker containers.  I'm trying to run Pulse as a standalone WAR running in Tomcat in a Docker also.  I can connect fine when running the Pulse WAR in Tomcat outside of the container so I suspect it's a ports or hostname issue.  I'm currently mapping 8080 inside the container to 8081.  I can load the Pulse UI in the browser but it keeps saying `"Connecting..."` in a yellowish box at the top of the page and doesn't find the Geode locator.

Looking in pulse.log, I see the following exception repeatedly:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

pulse.properties is configured to the defaults:

```
# JMX Locator/Manager Properties
pulse.useLocator=true
pulse.host=localhost
pulse.port=10334

#pulse.useSSL.locator=true
#pulse.useSSL.manager=true
```

Essentially I'm starting the Geode server/locator nodes with this command:

```
docker run -it -p 7070:7070 -p 10334:10334 -p 40404:40404 -p 40405:40405 -p 40406:40406 -p 1099:1099 apachegeode/geode
```

**What are the Docker ports that need to be open for Pulse to work and is there any specific hostname config required?**

Comment: In your pulse config, you set the host to localhost, I think you should set it to the geode server's docker container name and launch both pulse and geode in the same docker network. When you run a separate docker container, localhost translates to that particular container itself and not the host machine

Comment: Thanks @greenPadawan, I'll give that a go.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment from @greenPadawan (thanks) I solved this as follows:

Create a new network in Docker [ref](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/):  `docker network create --driver bridge geode`

Inside the Pulse WAR file at `/WEB-INF/classes/pulse.properties` I changed the `pulse.host=localhost` setting to `pulse.host=geode`.  I then re-built my Pulse Docker container with the updated WAR.

Start my two containers (one container for Geode and one for Pulse/Tomcat) both using that network:

```
docker run -it --network=geode --name geode -p 7070:7070 -p 10334:10334 -p 40404:40404 -p 40405:40405 -p 40406:40406 -p 1099:1099 apachegeode/geode
docker run -d -P --network=geode pulse
```

And when I now navigate to Pulse in the browser on the host machine, Pulse now connects to the Geode locator.